# Can I say "thanks" in the comments?

Tags: discussion

I know the "upvote" and "mark as answer" should be used for this porpouse but,
if someone answer my question and I like it, should/can I say thanks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote the [help page on the comment privilege](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When *shouldn't* I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer);
>
> ...

That being said, if someone goes out of there way to make a **really great answer** and you say thanks, you won't get in trouble for it but don't be surprised if it gets deleted after awhile because it doesn't meet the guidelines for a comment.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. To just say "thanks" is unnecessary and undesirable, but if someone really did a great job answering your question, and clearly put a good deal of effort into it, I believe expressing additional gratitude in that case is a positive for the community.

Answer (score 5):

there is no need for it the 10 rep of the upvote or 15 when accepted is more than enough, if you have something more substantial than a thanks go write that comment

the "thanks" comments is one of the reasons why there is a minimum character limit of 15